# C# Progressbar for a specified time

Tags: c#

I have this LINE:

```
int Time = textBox1.Text;
```

And a `ProgressBar`. I want the `ProgressBar` to be loading for a specific time - for example, 20 seconds. How can I do so? I was searching a lot but I couldn't figure out how to set the loading time.

Comment: Is this WinForms? WPF? Something else?

Comment: Try setting a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) and update the progress bar using that timer

Comment: If its WPF, set up an animation to update the progress.  It would be much smoother than using a timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
  System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
  timer1.Interval=1000;//1 second
  timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
  timer1.Start();
  progressBar1.Maximum = 20;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //do whatever you want
     if(progressBar1.Value==progressBar1.Maximum) 
        timer1.Stop();
     else
        progressBar1.Value+=1;
}
```